# XCode Project is not version controlled

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I have linux and svn server running and can terminal into it from my mac. In xcode I have setup a repositories and setup the folder structure branches, releases, tags, trunk for a project.

1. I have imported my first project into the trunk folder successfully.
2. I then create a different folder locally
3. In Xcode SCM, I navigate to /truck/ and click on it.
4. I click the checkout button and choose the location. It checks out successfully and prompts if I wish to open project so I do.

Everything appears fine but when I test by making changes to a file, I do not get any file status letters 'M' etc telling me that the file has be modified. It does not seem to be version controlled even though I have checked it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As well as `Foo.xcodeproj` (which is actually a directory, not a file, even though it looks like a file in the Finder), you also need to put `Foo.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` under version control, since this is where all the important project-related stuff is actually stored.

Don't bother putting anything else under `Foo.xcodeproj/` into version control - these are just user-specific settings: window positions, breakpoints, etc.